# List Manipulation prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I have write these lines of code in prolog

```
extend([],[]).
extend([(N,L)|T], [NewList|NewListT]):-
    fill((N,L),NewList),
    extend(T,NewListT).


fill((N,L),List) :-  
    length(List, N),
    maplist(=(L), List).
```

The thing i am trying to do is for a given `list=[(0, a), (0, b), (1, c)]` to create a `list=[[c]]`.
My problem is when i run the code i have this result `L = [[], [], [c]]`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `extend/2` adds a list to the result for each element of the incoming list. This needs to be filtered for non-empty lists. If I understood your requirement correctly based on your code and example, this should work:

```
extend([],[]).
extend([(N,L)|T], NewListFinal):-
    fill((N,L),NewList),
    extend(T,NewListT),
    (NewList=[]->NewListFinal=NewListT; NewListFinal=[NewList|NewListT]).
```

Example queries:

```
?- extend([(0, a), (0, b), (1, c)],L).
L = [[c]].

?- extend([(0, a), (3, b), (1, c)],L).
L = [[b, b, b], [c]].
```